# Wrapping javascript concatenated html correctly with ",' and \

Tags: javascript, html, html-escape-characters

I'm having a bit of trouble correctly displaying a message in a webpage I am trying to create. The code I have is:

```
content.innerHTML += "<button 'onclick=\"likeFunction(" + feed.messages[y]._id + ")\">" + "Like(" + feed.messages[y].likesCount + ")" + "</button>"
```

When I inspect the element on the page source, I get this output:

```
<button 'onclick="like(idOfObject)">Likes(likeNumber)</button>
```

What I need it to look like is:

```
<button 'onclick="like("idOfObject")">Likes(likeNumber)</button>
```

I'm a bit confused on how I would add more single or double quotes and where to escape them correctly to get this desired output.

Comment: you have a comma before onclick `'onclick="..."`

Comment: Use the `"` to surround the onclick function, and then surround each of the parameters inside the likeFunction with `'`

Comment: @Icepickle With your comment I got this far: content.innerHTML += "<button onclick=\"likeFunction('" + 'feed.messages[y]._id' + "' )\">" + "Like(" + feed.messages[y].likesCount + ")" + "</button>". In the output I am getting it sent as a string, but the string being sent is the literal variable and not the data inside the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're so close! First, you need to remove the `'` before `onclick`. If you want to add double quotes around the `idOfObject`, then you just need escape one double quote after `likeFunction(` and one double quote before `)\">"`.

```
"<button onclick=\"likeFunction(\"" + feed.messages[y]._id + "\")\">"
```

The only problem is that when the double quotes around your variable `idOfObject` render, they'll correspond to the opening and closing quotes you already have for `onclick`. So, your solution should have single quotes inside of double quotes:

```
"<button onclick=\"likeFunction(\'" + feed.messages[y]._id + "\')\">"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I see a few typos. Most noticeably with the leading ' in front of onclick. I don't think this needs to be here.

As for formatting the string, consider looking into [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) introduced in ES6.

Might look something like this:

```
content.innerHTML += `<button onclick="likeFunction(${idOfObjectVariable})">Likes (${likeCountVariable})</button>`
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would have guessed what you wanted in your HTML would be:

```
<button onclick="like('idOfObject')">7</button>
```

or

```
<button onclick='like("idOfObject")'>7</button>
```

You probably do not want to quote the entire on-click attribute, just the part on the right hand side of the `=` .

```
content.innerHTML += "<button onclick=\"like('" + feed.messages[y]._id + "')\">" + ...
```

I'm guessing you also probably don't want something that gets displayed to the user that looks like a function all, but the result of the function call, but that is not what you were asking about.

Answer (score 0):

You ***SHOULD NOT*** concatenate html manually from untrusted input (suppose someone injected malicious html code to your feed.messages[y]._id or another field). Sanitization is one of your options but it's like patching a huge hole.
You can read more about preventing those security attacks named XSS [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Consider creating your DOM manualy with `createElement` API and bind your event handlers manually.

```
function renderButton(content, feed, y) {
    function likeFunction() {
      alert("LIKE" + feed.messages[y]._id);
    };

    var button = document.createElement("button");
    var text = document.createTextNode("Like(" + feed.messages[y].likesCount + ")");
    button.appendChild(text);
    button.addEventListener('click', likeFunction)
    content.appendChild(button);
}
```

Then you can just render your button with a simple function call.

```
renderButton(content, feed, 0)
```